# Difference between adding path to PYTHONPATH and installing your own module

Tags: python, module, packaging

I'm working on a python project that contains a number of routines I use repeatedly. Instead of rewriting code all the time, I just want to update my package and import it; however, it's nowhere near done and is constantly changing. I host the package on a repo so that colleagues on various machines (UNIX + Windows) can pull it into their local repos and use it.

It sounds like I have two options, either I can keeping installing the package after every change or I can just add the folder directory to my system's path. If I change the package, does it need to be reinstalled? [I'm using this blog post as inspiration](http://www.kennethreitz.org/essays/repository-structure-and-python), but the author there doesn't stress the issue of a continuously changing package structure, so I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Also if I wanted to split the project into multiple files and bundle it as a package, at what level in the directory structure does the PTYHONPATH need to be at? To the main project directory, or the .sample/ directory?

```
README.rst
LICENSE
setup.py
requirements.txt
sample/__init__.py
sample/core.py
sample/helpers.py
docs/conf.py
docs/index.rst
tests/test_basic.py
tests/test_advanced.py
```

In this example, I want to be able to just import the package itself and call the modules within it like this:

```
import sample

arg = sample.helper.foo()
out = sample.core.bar(arg)

return out
```

Where core contains a function called foo

Answer (score 0):

PYTHONPATH is a valid way of doing this, but in my (personal) opinion it's more useful if you have a whole different place where you keep your python variables. Like `/opt/pythonpkgs` or so.

For projects where I want it to be installed and also I have to keep developing, I use `develop` instead of `install` in setup.py:

When installing the package, don't do:

```
python setup.py install
```

Rather, do:

```
python setup.py develop
```

What this does is that it creates a synlink/shortcut (I believe it's called egglink in python) in the python libs (where the packages are installed) to point to your module's directory. Hence, as it's a shortcut/symlink/egglink when ever you change a python file, it will immediately reflect the next time you import that file.

Note: Using this, if you delete the repository/directory you ran this command from, the package will cease to exist (as its only a shortcut)

The equivalent in `pip` is -e (for editable):

```
pip install -e .
```

Instead of:

```
pip install .
```

Comment: in your example, /opt/pythonpkgs is on the PYTHONPATH, and each package within its own directory. Does the pythonpkgs directory need to contain an __init__.py file? Does each package within that directory also need one?

Comment: `/opt/pythonpkgs/__init__.py` does not need to exist. `/opt/pythonpkgs/my_first_pkg/__init__.py` should exist.